# unable to get firebase packages in flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I did every thing from official get started tutorial to forms 
whenever i try to add packages in `pubspec.ymal` file

like

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
sdk: flutter
firebase_auth:
```

get an error

> Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.

```
21 │ ┌     sdk: flutter
22 │ │     firebase_auth:
27 │ │   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
   │ └──^
pub get failed (65)
exit code 65
```

this is same as I add

```
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
```

my `flutter doctor -v`
the output is as follow

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418], locale en-US)

```
• Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at D:\C\flutter
• Framework revision 68587a0916 (7 weeks ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
• Engine revision b863200c37
• Dart version 2.5.0
```

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)

```
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
• All Android licenses accepted.
```

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)

```
• Flutter plugin version 41.0.2
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
```

[√] Connected device (1 available)

```
• Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
```

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with your syntax: Delete backspace from firebase_auth
write firebase in same line as cupertino...try this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth:
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```